# How to programmatically sort a DataView bound to a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have an already populated DataTable bound to two DataGrids:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = _dataTable.DefaultView;
dataGrid2.DataContext = _dataTable.DefaultView;
```

Also I have two buttons, which programmatically sort the underlying DataView:

```
private void buttonSortAsc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "[Name] ASC";
}

private void buttonSortDesc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "[Name] DESC";
}
```

If I press the sort buttons, the data gets sorted and the DataGrids reflect the change in the sort order. That's ok.

Clicking the column headers of either the one or the other DataGrid I can sort the content of the DataGrid and the change will be reflected in both DataGrids. So far, so good.

But as of having sorted the data by clicking a DataGrid's column header, the programmatic sorting by clicking the buttons which initiate the

```
_dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "[Name] ASC";
```

or

```
_dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "[Name] DESC";
```

will no longer reflect the change of the sort order to the DataGrids.

I want to achieve that a programmatic sorting of a DataView is reflected on a DataGrid as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.